# WiFi doesn't work since 11.10 thought it would be fixed on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, realtek

My wireless adapter is **RTL8191SEvB**. The driver which has been working was the **rtl819xSE**, but when I upgraded to 11.10, it just stopped working and nothing changed after upgrading to 12.04.

I really don't know if that's a problem with Ubuntu or with the kernel. Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: It seems like that is a very problematic adapter for Linux.  Can it be replaced?  I had a wireless card in an old Dell that was a problem, so I replaced it with an Intel card I got on Amazon for about $15, and then it always works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

your wireless card is perhaps blocked

you need to use rfkill command with sudo rights

this is documentation for rfkill :
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/rfkill

A successful attempt by one user : 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1851923

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this driver?

(The 8191SE one)

http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8188CE

The reason it's probably not working is because the driver only officially supports the Linux Kernel up to 3.2, while 12.10 has Kernel 3.5. So it may not work until Realtek updates their driver.